# Is it possible to instantiate a DataFrame with a unicode column?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create a `DataFrame` that has a column that stores `unicode` data instead of standard python `string`, because my language has some additional accented letters, e.g. `ñ, á, é` and others.

I tried the following.

```
x = sqlContext.createDataFrame([u"A", u"B", u"C"], ["letters"])
```

And showed the next exception.

> TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <.type 'unicode'>

Then I read the [type documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=type#module-pyspark.sql.types) and didn't find compatible data type, therefore I ask if someone knows if it's possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you provide the elements not `unicode` data. Even if you have only a single column every element should be of supported type like `Row`, `list` or `tuple`:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(u"A", ), (u"B", ), (u"C", )], ["letters"])
```

Comment: This question looks useless, but I bet many persons will have this problem in the future